# How to copy files using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

I need to create a batch file to copy certain files (e.g., 19_1_White.jpg) to a folder within the directory. How can I do this?

Answer (score 18):

```
XCOPY F:\*.* G:\ /C /S /D /Y /I

XCOPY allows for copying of files, directories, and sub directories.
F:\*.* is our source location
G:\ is our destination location
/C tells XCOPY to ignore errors, and finish what can be done
/S tells XCOPY to copy everything including directories and
subdirectories
/D tells XCOPY to only copy source files that are newer than the
destination files (big time saver on the process)
/Y tells XCOPY to overwrite files without asking for confirmation
/I tells XCOPY to automatically create new directories on the
destination, if new directories were created in source.
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to use the command XCOPY
eg XCOPY A.jpg C:\Folder\A.jpg

Take a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/289483/switches-that-you-can-use-with-xcopy-and-xcopy32-commands for any other switches you may want to use too.